# How to align all View Details buttons inline on all category pages

Tags: magento-1.9, product, css, inline

How to align all View Details buttons inline on all category pages. I think i have to fix the names of all products, if this is fixed then all the View Details buttons get aligned inline. I don't know how to do this. I am not familiar with CSS. My website is mobile friendly & responsive. How to fix this issue. For better understanding I had uploaded the screenshot. 
[image]

list.phtml

```
    <?php
/**
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
/* @var $this Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List */
?>
<?php
    /* Count for timer calculation declared here */
    $count = 1;
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                <?php /* Based on the native RWD styling, product images are displayed at a max of ~400px wide when viewed on a
                        one column page layout with four product columns from a 1280px viewport. For bandwidth reasons,
                        we are going to serve a 300px image, as it will look fine at 400px and most of the times, the image
                        will be displayed at a smaller size (eg, if two column are being used or viewport is smaller than 1280px).
                        This $_imgSize value could even be decreased further, based on the page layout
                        (one column, two column, three column) and number of product columns. */ ?>
                <?php $_imgSize = 300; ?>
                <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                     src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                     alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
            </a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <div class="product-primary">
                        <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php
                            $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                            foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
                                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                        ?>
                            <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-secondary">
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    </div>
                    <!--Condition for Timer Controllers goes here-->
                    <?php if($this->getPriceCountDown($_product)) :?>
                        <?php if (Mage::helper('timer')->isShowTitle('listpage')): ?>
                            <div id="heading<?php echo $count; ?>"  class="timer-heading" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;padding-top:0px;clear: both;">
                                <?php echo Mage::helper('timer')->getTimerTitle(); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div id="countbox_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="timer-list"></div>
                        <?php if (Mage::helper('timer')->isShowCaption('listpage')): ?>
                            <div class='clear'></div>
                            <div class='timerdate' id="caption<?php echo $count; ?>">
                                <span class='hour' style='margin:0'><?php echo $this->__('D') ?></span>
                                <span class='hour' style='margin:0 0 0 25px'><?php echo $this->__('H') ?></span>
                                <span class='min'  style='margin:0 0 0 22px'><?php echo $this->__('M') ?></span>
                                <span class='sec' style='margin:0 0 0 23px'><?php echo $this->__('S') ?></span>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <!--Condition for Timer Controllers End -->
                    <div class="product-secondary">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable() && !$_product->canConfigure()): ?>
                            <p class="action"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                        <?php elseif($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <p class="action"><a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a></p>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="action availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if($this->getPriceCountDown($_product)) :?>
                <?php $toDate = $_product->getSpecialTODate();?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var dthen<?php echo $count; ?> = new Date("<?php echo Date("m/d/y", strtotime($toDate)).' 11:59:00 PM'; ?>");
                    start = "<?php echo Date("m/d/y h:i:s A", strtotime(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::date(null, null, "en_US", true))); ?>";
                    start_date = Date.parse(start);
                    var dnow<?php echo $count; ?> = new Date(start_date);
                    if(CountStepper>0)
                    ddiff= new Date((dnow<?php echo $count; ?>)-(dthen<?php echo $count; ?>));
                    else
                    ddiff = new Date((dthen<?php echo $count; ?>)-(dnow<?php echo $count; ?>));
                    gsecs<?php echo $count; ?> = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
                    var iid<?php echo $count; ?> = "countbox_<?php echo $count; ?>";
                    CountBack(gsecs<?php echo $count; ?>,"countbox_"+timer, timer);
                    timer++;
                </script>
                <?php $count = $count + 1; ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
    <?php endif ?>
            <?php /*if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
            <?php endif*/ ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                    <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                         src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                         alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                </a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>

                    <?php
                        $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                        foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
                            $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                            $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                    ?>
                        <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <!--Condition for Timer Controllers goes here-->
                    <?php if($this->getPriceCountDown($_product)) :?>
                        <?php if (Mage::helper('timer')->isShowTitle('listpage')): ?>
                            <div id="heading<?php echo $count; ?>" class="timer-heading" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;padding-top:0px;clear: both;">
                                <?php echo Mage::helper('timer')->getTimerTitle(); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div id="countbox_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="timer-list"></div>
                        <?php if (Mage::helper('timer')->isShowCaption('listpage')): ?>
                            <div class='clear'></div>
                            <div class='timerdate' id="caption<?php echo $count; ?>">
                                <span class='hour' style='margin:0'><?php echo $this->__('D') ?></span>
                                <span class='hour' style='margin:0 0 0 25px'><?php echo $this->__('H') ?></span>
                                <span class='min'  style='margin:0 0 0 20px'><?php echo $this->__('M') ?></span>
                                <span class='sec' style='margin:0 0 0 23px'><?php echo $this->__('S') ?></span>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <!--Condition for Timer Controllers End -->
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable() && !$_product->canConfigure()): ?>
                                 <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></span></span></button>
                        <?php elseif($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                   <?php if($this->getPriceCountDown($_product)) :?>
                    <?php $toDate = $_product->getSpecialTODate();?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var dthen<?php echo $count; ?> = new Date("<?php echo Date("m/d/y", strtotime($toDate)).' 11:59:00 PM'; ?>");
                        start = "<?php echo Date("m/d/y h:i:s A", strtotime(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::date(null, null, "en_US", true))); ?>";
                        start_date = Date.parse(start);
                        var dnow<?php echo $count; ?> = new Date(start_date);
                        if(CountStepper>0)
                            ddiff= new Date((dnow<?php echo $count; ?>)-(dthen<?php echo $count; ?>));
                        else
                            ddiff = new Date((dthen<?php echo $count; ?>)-(dnow<?php echo $count; ?>));
                        gsecs<?php echo $count; ?> = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
                        var iid<?php echo $count; ?> = "countbox_<?php echo $count; ?>";
                        CountBack(gsecs<?php echo $count; ?>,"countbox_"+timer, timer);
                        timer++;
                    </script>
                    <?php $count = $count + 1; ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
            </li>
      <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
    //set product collection on after blocks
    $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName):
        $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
        $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
    ?>
    <?php echo $_afterChild->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<!--  Timer Script Start here -->
<?php 
/* Admin Controllers for timer are declared here */
$timer_color = Mage::getStoreConfig('timer/apptha_timer_color/text');
$desc_color = Mage::getStoreConfig('timer/apptha_timer_color/description');
$head_color = Mage::getStoreConfig('timer/apptha_timer_color/heading_text_color');
?>

<!--  Timer Script End here -->
<!--Dynamic style changes goes here-->
<style>
.timer-list{float: left;width: 100%;padding: 0;color: #<?php echo $timer_color; ?>;font-size: 18px;font-family:arial;font-weight: bold;}
.timerdate{float: left;width: 100%;padding:0 0 3px 0;color: #<?php echo $desc_color; ?>;font-size: 12px;}
.timer-heading{color:#<?php echo $head_color;?>;}
</style>
```

Comment: The issue is due to your products name. You can trim it to fit into two lines.

Comment: how to trim this @Jaimin

Comment: You can use substr function to achieve this.

Comment: can you please provide the code

Comment: Can you please add your catalog/product/list.phtml code to question?

Comment: Okzz no problem wait i will add

Comment: I had added the list.phtml code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code for your **list.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
/* @var $this Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List */
?>
<?php
    /* Count for timer calculation declared here */
    $count = 1;
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                <?php /* Based on the native RWD styling, product images are displayed at a max of ~400px wide when viewed on a
                        one column page layout with four product columns from a 1280px viewport. For bandwidth reasons,
                        we are going to serve a 300px image, as it will look fine at 400px and most of the times, the image
                        will be displayed at a smaller size (eg, if two column are being used or viewport is smaller than 1280px).
                        This $_imgSize value could even be decreased further, based on the page layout
                        (one column, two column, three column) and number of product columns. */ ?>
                <?php $_imgSize = 300; ?>
                <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                     src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                     alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
            </a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <div class="product-primary">
                        <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo mb_strimwidth($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'), 0, 25, '...')?></a></h2>
                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php
                            $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                            foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
                                $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                        ?>
                            <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-secondary">
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    </div>
                    <!--Condition for Timer Controllers goes here-->
                    <?php if($this->getPriceCountDown($_product)) :?>
                        <?php if (Mage::helper('timer')->isShowTitle('listpage')): ?>
                            <div id="heading<?php echo $count; ?>"  class="timer-heading" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;padding-top:0px;clear: both;">
                                <?php echo Mage::helper('timer')->getTimerTitle(); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div id="countbox_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="timer-list"></div>
                        <?php if (Mage::helper('timer')->isShowCaption('listpage')): ?>
                            <div class='clear'></div>
                            <div class='timerdate' id="caption<?php echo $count; ?>">
                                <span class='hour' style='margin:0'><?php echo $this->__('D') ?></span>
                                <span class='hour' style='margin:0 0 0 25px'><?php echo $this->__('H') ?></span>
                                <span class='min'  style='margin:0 0 0 22px'><?php echo $this->__('M') ?></span>
                                <span class='sec' style='margin:0 0 0 23px'><?php echo $this->__('S') ?></span>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <!--Condition for Timer Controllers End -->
                    <div class="product-secondary">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable() && !$_product->canConfigure()): ?>
                            <p class="action"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                        <?php elseif($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <p class="action"><a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a></p>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="action availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if($this->getPriceCountDown($_product)) :?>
                <?php $toDate = $_product->getSpecialTODate();?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var dthen<?php echo $count; ?> = new Date("<?php echo Date("m/d/y", strtotime($toDate)).' 11:59:00 PM'; ?>");
                    start = "<?php echo Date("m/d/y h:i:s A", strtotime(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::date(null, null, "en_US", true))); ?>";
                    start_date = Date.parse(start);
                    var dnow<?php echo $count; ?> = new Date(start_date);
                    if(CountStepper>0)
                    ddiff= new Date((dnow<?php echo $count; ?>)-(dthen<?php echo $count; ?>));
                    else
                    ddiff = new Date((dthen<?php echo $count; ?>)-(dnow<?php echo $count; ?>));
                    gsecs<?php echo $count; ?> = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
                    var iid<?php echo $count; ?> = "countbox_<?php echo $count; ?>";
                    CountBack(gsecs<?php echo $count; ?>,"countbox_"+timer, timer);
                    timer++;
                </script>
                <?php $count = $count + 1; ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
    <?php endif ?>
            <?php /*if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
            <?php endif*/ ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                    <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                         src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                         alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                </a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo mb_strimwidth($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'), 0, 25, '...')?></a></h2>

                    <?php
                        $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                        foreach($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName):
                            $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                            $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                    ?>
                        <?php echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml(); ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <!--Condition for Timer Controllers goes here-->
                    <?php if($this->getPriceCountDown($_product)) :?>
                        <?php if (Mage::helper('timer')->isShowTitle('listpage')): ?>
                            <div id="heading<?php echo $count; ?>" class="timer-heading" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;padding-top:0px;clear: both;">
                                <?php echo Mage::helper('timer')->getTimerTitle(); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div id="countbox_<?php echo $count; ?>" class="timer-list"></div>
                        <?php if (Mage::helper('timer')->isShowCaption('listpage')): ?>
                            <div class='clear'></div>
                            <div class='timerdate' id="caption<?php echo $count; ?>">
                                <span class='hour' style='margin:0'><?php echo $this->__('D') ?></span>
                                <span class='hour' style='margin:0 0 0 25px'><?php echo $this->__('H') ?></span>
                                <span class='min'  style='margin:0 0 0 20px'><?php echo $this->__('M') ?></span>
                                <span class='sec' style='margin:0 0 0 23px'><?php echo $this->__('S') ?></span>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <!--Condition for Timer Controllers End -->
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable() && !$_product->canConfigure()): ?>
                                 <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></span></span></button>
                        <?php elseif($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                   <?php if($this->getPriceCountDown($_product)) :?>
                    <?php $toDate = $_product->getSpecialTODate();?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var dthen<?php echo $count; ?> = new Date("<?php echo Date("m/d/y", strtotime($toDate)).' 11:59:00 PM'; ?>");
                        start = "<?php echo Date("m/d/y h:i:s A", strtotime(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::date(null, null, "en_US", true))); ?>";
                        start_date = Date.parse(start);
                        var dnow<?php echo $count; ?> = new Date(start_date);
                        if(CountStepper>0)
                            ddiff= new Date((dnow<?php echo $count; ?>)-(dthen<?php echo $count; ?>));
                        else
                            ddiff = new Date((dthen<?php echo $count; ?>)-(dnow<?php echo $count; ?>));
                        gsecs<?php echo $count; ?> = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
                        var iid<?php echo $count; ?> = "countbox_<?php echo $count; ?>";
                        CountBack(gsecs<?php echo $count; ?>,"countbox_"+timer, timer);
                        timer++;
                    </script>
                    <?php $count = $count + 1; ?>
                    <?php endif;?>
            </li>
      <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
    //set product collection on after blocks
    $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName):
        $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
        $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
    ?>
    <?php echo $_afterChild->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<!--  Timer Script Start here -->
<?php 
/* Admin Controllers for timer are declared here */
$timer_color = Mage::getStoreConfig('timer/apptha_timer_color/text');
$desc_color = Mage::getStoreConfig('timer/apptha_timer_color/description');
$head_color = Mage::getStoreConfig('timer/apptha_timer_color/heading_text_color');
?>

<!--  Timer Script End here -->
<!--Dynamic style changes goes here-->
<style>
.timer-list{float: left;width: 100%;padding: 0;color: #<?php echo $timer_color; ?>;font-size: 18px;font-family:arial;font-weight: bold;}
.timerdate{float: left;width: 100%;padding:0 0 3px 0;color: #<?php echo $desc_color; ?>;font-size: 12px;}
.timer-heading{color:#<?php echo $head_color;?>;}
.product-name{ min-height:40px !important; } 
.price { font-size:15px !important; }
</style>
```

Comment: I had used your code but still the View Details button are not getting aligned

Comment: Can you see ... After your products names?

Comment: NO nothing has changed @Jaimin

Comment: There are two instances of this line in your list.phtml. Please replace both of them

Comment: Okzz i will check n get back to u

Comment: I had done the changes in 2 instances but still nothing happened

Comment: I had done the changes in both my theme & base theme list.phtml files but no changes occur

Comment: Please replace your list.phtml file code with above updated code.

Comment: I had replaced the code still no changes @Jaimin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59484/discussion-between-jaimin-sutariya-and-salman-dalal).